# Issues with wireless charging receiver circuit

Tags: wireless-charging

Circuit is not functioning as intended, just get repeating pulses Vrect ~= 2.5V. I understand Vrect needs to be above this value but I having trouble getting there.

AC1 PAD 1 & AC2 Pad2 are connected to the receiver coil with part number listed. This is intended to be a WPC 1.2 compliant receiver circuit used with off the shelf transmitters. The BQ51003 chip is to be used as a 5v power supply. The power transmission never gets further than the initial ping. I believe it is due to low voltage at the Vrect pin, as that voltage never gets higher than the undervoltage lockout value.  This leads me to believe the issue is with the resonant circuit and I am needing advice on how to go about fine tuning the resonant circuit to get the required voltage.

[image: Wireless Receiver schematic]

Ls' ~= 33uH
Ls  ~= 29uH

Comment: saying `not functioning as intended` is meaningless if you do not say what is the intended function, and if you do not say what is the observed functioning

Comment: Where are the inductors in the schematic you mention?

Comment: Added additional information to post. Thanks!!

Comment: @dvdmeece_OI what is your question? Ask a specific question, you'll get better answers and the moderators won't have to close down the question for being off topic